# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'apply'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am receiving this Uncaught TypeError on a new website I am creating, but I can't work out what is causing the error.

I have recreated the issue at the link below, if you take a look at your browsers JS console you'll see the error occurring, but nothing else happens.

http://jsfiddle.net/EbR6D/2/

Code:

```
$('.newsitem').hover(
$(this).children('.text').animate({ height: '34px' }), 
$(this).children('.text').animate({ height: '0px'  }));​
```

Comment: Where is `.text` in the HTML?

Comment: sorry, that should have read .title

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Be sure to wrap those in asynchronous callbacks:

```
$('.newsitem').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).children('.title').animate({height:'34px'});
    }, function() {
        $(this).children('.title').animate({height:'0px'});
    }
);
​
```

Answer (score 3):

You need:

```
.hover(function(){ ... });
```

as per the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/hover/).

Comment: lol I can't believe I stared at that code for more than a minute and didn't notice he isn't passing a function :P

Comment: Thanks, knew it would be obvious. but I just couldn't see it.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the `function`...

```
$('.newsitem').hover(
    $(this).children('.text').animate({height:'34px'}),
    $(this).children('.text').animate({height:'0px'})
);
```

To:

```
$('.newsitem').hover(function() {
    $(this).children('.text').animate({
        height: '34px'
    });
}, function() {
    $(this).children('.text').animate({
        height: '0px'
    });
});​
​
```

And the ​`$(this).children('.text')`, is not selecting anything.

Answer (score 0):

use slide animation to handle hight of the .text class.

```
$('.newsitem').hover(function() {
    $(this).children('.text').slideToggle();
});​
​
```