# Backbone bind event keydown to document returns Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'apply'

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, keyboard-events, keydown

I am having big trouble fixing this error.

I have a view in Backbone.js and I want to bind some actions on it with keyboard events.

Here is my view :

```
window.PicturesView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize : function() {
        $(document).on('keydown', this.keyboard, this);
    },
    remove : function() {
        $(document).off('keydown', this.keyboard, this);
    },
    render : function(eventName) {
        // blah blah blah
    },
    next : function() {
        // blah
    },
    prev : function() {
        // blah
    },
    keyboard : function(e) {
        console.log(e.keyCode);
        if (e.keyCode == 37) {
            this.prev();
            return false;
        }
        if (e.keyCode == 39) {
            this.next();
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

When I press the keyboard, I get this error :
`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'apply'` 
that is triggered by jQuery.

After reading this : [Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'apply'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032659/uncaught-typeerror-object-object-object-has-no-method-apply)

I also tried :
        `$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
            this.keyboard(e);
        }, this);`
but it still gives me the same error.

And :
        `$(document).on('keydown', 'keyboard', this);`
in the `events : { 'event' : 'action' }` style
but it doesn't do anything.

I could probably find some hack by using jQuery only somewhere else in my code, but since I am not expert in event handling and Backbone, I want to run it the nice way.

I hope I'm clear, thanks

Comment: [That's not the correct usage of `on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@roatin-marth was right. The "on" function that was applying wasn't the backbone one as I expected, which allows to pass the context as a parameter :
`$(document).on('keydown', this.keyboard, this);`

Since it's a jQuery selector, it's the jQuery on that applies. Hence I need a proxy to link with context:
`$(document).on('keydown',$.proxy(this.keyboard,this));`

All good, thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

The typical events syntax for Backbone should work. Get rid of the initialize code and try it.

```
// code above unaltered
initialize : function() { }, // of course you can remove these two, it was just to clarify that they should be empty.

remove : function() { },

render : function(eventName) {
    // blah blah blah
    this.delegateEvents(); // just to have them re-bound if the view is removed
},

events: {
    'keydown': 'keyboard'
}
// rest of the code unaltered
```

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't work. Apparently the keypress listener only applies to document and not to subcode. Or it is a focus issue which I don't want to handle since I want the listener to apply from anywhere in the document. I'll write down the answer.